# How to define 2 serializers for model in Ember-CLI?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I have model `Record` and I made serializer for it which in file serializers/record.js with code

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: 'record_id'
});
```

But I want to create JSONSerializer with `primaryKey: 'record_id'`. How can I add it?

But the main problem that I want to get history from API url consultation/:id/history?loadToId=:id and I can't do it with ember built-in tools, so I get it with `jQuery.ajax` and try to push into store with `this.get('store').pushPayload('record', record)`

Please advise me with that problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the JSON serializer instead of the rest serializer. Just change your code to

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: 'record_id'
});
```

Comment: But I want to use in one case RESTSerializer and in other case JSONSerializer. So I need to define two of them